# Outswing French doors: are they doable without a porch roof?

Tags: doors

We'd like to install outswing French doors leading out to our patio. Does anyone have comments about the practicality of this if the patio does not have any covering/roof over it?  It is a patio, not a porch.

We've been thinking we won't open the French doors when it is raining.

Also we won't open them when it is windy, to avoid the door being snagged by the wind and yanked out of our hands.

Good enough?  Other problems we aren't forseeing?

We would have the install done by a contractor we've used before, and we would specify that he use flashing not just caulk, a good practice in general.

Our concern is really just the issue of the doors opening outwards onto a patio that does not have a roof.  Our house's roof overhang over where the the new door would be is about 24".

Comment: Don't all french doors open this way?  Isn't it the definition of french doors to do this?

Answer (score 2):

Many doors open outwards into spaces without a roof over them. More of them are commercial than residential, but that has more to do with "common choices in residential doors" and "commercial egress door codes" than any inherent problem with it.

Unless there's a snowdrift against it, not generally a problem.

Comment: When isn't there a snowdrift against a door.  Doors are snowdrift magnets.